# Page Tab Facebook v2.1 changes : How to see if fan liked the page now?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

as by [this note](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mktpkruu8kez6vt/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202014-08-08%2014.10.10.png) on [Facebook doc for Fields for Signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request), it seems that we don't have access to know if the user has liked the page or not, through Page Tabs (in my case).

I searched for a replacement for this and could come up with a valid solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no replacement, it is just not possible anymore to create fan gates in new Apps and old Apps will always return "true" in the "liked" parameter of `signed_request`.

This is intentional, users should Like a Page because they really want to, not because some promotion forces them to.

Comment: Ok I see!  woops ... and then, services like woobox.com won't be able to offer that feature anymore either?

Comment: nope, no service will be able to offer that feature after november :)